# python coordinate transformation / interpolation possible?

Tags: python, geocoding, transformation, coordinate-transformation

Hy there!

I am actually working on some geodata datasets. I am using python and pygrib to read the original data. pygrib returns wonderfull longitude/latitude values for my "rotated" grid (see plot). What i have to do is to bring the data onto an orthogonal geo-longitude/latitude (so a meshgrid). 
It is no problem to do it by hand BUT i think that python has a package which does it for me? If yes i hanvt found any good hint in the web.

pygrib seems to know enough about the projection to compute my latlons. So i guess that there is a package somewhere which transforms (with interpolation) my data into another projection? :)

Probably there is someone out there which can give me some hints and/or links. Would be great!

Thanks and best wishes
Reto Stauffer, Austria

[image]

Comment: Reto, your question is very, very specific. There may be someone in Stack Overflow that knows the answer, but I think you stand a better chance if you ask instead in forums/mailing lists related to pygrib

Comment: Potentially gis.stackexchange.com as well would have experts more tailored to this. I know they often discuss Python code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GDAL, there is a [commandlinetools](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) to do this.

You can import the ogr module from the gdal library into python, start [here](http://www.gdal.org/), but the commandlinetool did the trick for me in a similar case.

Comment: GDAL also has a Python interface.